# Determine the minimal exponential family form

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ having p.d.f of the form $$f(x|\theta)=\exp\{c(\theta)'T(x)-B(\theta)\}h(x),$$
then we say $X$ is from exponential family. Further, we say that an exponential family is *minimal* if the functions $c(\theta)$ and the statistics $T(X)$, are linearly independent respectively.

I am trying to determine the minimal exponential family form of the following case.

Here, $X$ has p.d.f $$f(x|\alpha,\beta)=\exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}(\alpha+\beta z_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+\exp(\alpha+\beta z_i))\right\},$$

which is equal to

$$f(x|\alpha,\beta)=\exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i}\alpha + \sum_{i=1}^n\beta z_ix_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\log(1+\exp(\alpha+\beta z_i))\right\}$$

For the first equation the natural sufficient statistic $T$ is , $T=(X_1, \dots,X_n)$, while the second is $T=(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\sum_{i=1}^nX_iz_i)$.

**I wonder which one is the minimal exponential family form.**